# In-place delta writes from a pipe

Tags: linux, bash, pipe, btrfs, deduplication

I'm looking for a way to only overwrites the parts of a file that differ from what's supposed to be written to it, so that the file is changed with the least amount of writes to disk possible.

My plan is to do a bit of deduplication while I'm backing up my NTFS partition to an image file by having that image file be a reflinked copy of a previous backup image on a BTRFS.
(Think of it as a hardlink that you can write to without changing the original file)

I'm padding the unused parts of my NTFS partition with zeroes by piping `partclone` into itself, so the input is a pipe instead of a device.
Think of it as

`cat /dev/sda4 | command -i - -o newbackup.img`

where `command` is what I'm looking for and `newbackup.img` is a file that already holds 894GiB of data which is largely the same as the input but the actual disk usage of the image file is equal to the amount blocks that are overwritten.

`rsync` can do this with the `--no-whole-file --inplace` parameters (IIRC) thanks to it's delta transfer but it's unnecessarily slow (doesn't read in- and output concurrently, processes the deltas on a single thread and is generally *very* time inefficient) and `rsync` also doesn't work with pipes (to my knowledge), so it's out of the question.

Comment: There are tools for making "binary" patches, and applying the patches, see e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1945075/how-do-i-create-binary-patches). Is that what you need? Pipes are serial by definition, you won't be able to seek in a pipe, so no in-place delta writes, but you should be able to create a binary patch from a pipe and an existing file (though I didn't test that).

Comment: I don't quite understand why you'd have to seek seeking a pipe for in-place delta writes, shouldn't it be completely sequential? In my mind it'd work like this: Read n bits from pipe; read n bits from file; if they're not equal, overwrite those n bits in the file; repeat with the next n bits.

Comment: Ah, I didn't understand that this is what you mean by "in-place delta writes" - my understanding was "in-place" = on an existing file, not making a copy, and "delta writes" = write only those parts that change. As for "read n bits from pipe and from file, overwrite if not equal": such a program is simple to write. But it would be more efficient to just overwrite the file: You have now n block writes instead of n block reads and m block writes, where m is the number of changed blocks. Unless you want to avoid writes for some reason, because on your medium they are more expensive than reads.

Comment: @dirkt CoW behavior of Btrfs is the reason. Overwriting any part of a reflinked file makes the part take its own space on the device, instead of sharing blocks on filesystem level. This happens even if you overwrite with the same data, this is the point. Leaving unchanged parts intact saves space on the device.

Comment: Looks like the real fix should be a BTRFS option... anyway, as I said, the program is easy to write. Couple of lines of C code, more if you want to set blocksize etc.

Comment: Somewhat related: [*Command to DD Write Only if Different?*](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/538638/108618)